# Split columns in SSIS into a numeric part and the remainder of the column value

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to figure out how to convert my existing DTS files to DTSX hosted on a SQL 2005 server.

In my first try (first DTS) I'm already stuck.

I don't wanna look how things are done using DTS and wanna focus on the new DTSX techniques.

What has to be done.

- Check if input file exists else exit.(not done yet)
- Truncate destination table
- Import file into DB
- Report if everything was alright.

step import file is where I'm stuck. I have a fixed columns sized flat tekst file where housenumber and extension are in a single column. The Database has two columns for it.

I first tried a derived column but could find a check for splittng the (first) numeric part.

When searching for the use of regex i read about the "script component" which i read isn't compatible with SQL 2005.

Is there another possibility?

This brings me to a second question: Is it possible to use SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) with SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Can you post sample data for `housenumber` and `extension`

Comment: it is simply a numeric part with and extension: could be "2B", "24 A", "15 II" or something like that. So i want the numeric first part. followed by something (everything) that isn't numeric (could be a whitespace folowed by another numeric part)

Comment: AFAIK SSIS doesn't have any function to use `Wildcards` to perform `Regular Expression Matches` but you can always use `Script component` to extract the number and string .Ex `@"\d+"` or `[A-Za-z]+` .BTW why `Script component isn't compatible with SQL 2005` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a job ahead of you.  You will need to use [Derived Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx) transformations, so look them up.  It will be helpful to add [Data Viewers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140318.aspx) to your dataflows so you can see what data is moving through the flow, and what SSIS thinks is in there.

In your case, you are going to have to manipulate strings.  There are two string data types, DT_STR and DT_WSTR (e.g., VARCHAR and NVARCHAR).  SSIS is very particular about data types, and you may have to convert one type into the other using cast operations.  E.g., (DT_WSTR, 50)Blah converts fifty characters from column Blah into DT_WSTR. The DT_STR type also needs to know the code page,. e.g. something like 1252.

You will likely need the SSIS version of [Immediate If](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141680.aspx), which checks if a condition is true, and returns either one result or the other:  Blah==100?1:0  The result of this will be a 1 for those records where column Blah equals 100, and 0 for all other records.  You can nest these Immediate If statements, with one inside the next, inside the next, adn so forth.

You will need at least two new columns being created in the Derived Column widget, one for the numbers, and one for what follows.  So here is one very painful way to do what you want.  Use a string function to check whether the first character is a number, and then either return it, or don't.  Do the same for the second character, etc.

Of course, I'm sure there's a better way to do this.  Your toolbox consists of the functions in the Derived Column widget, so that's what you've got to work with.  (Or, alternatively, you might do better in this case with a SQL UPDATE statement, which you would execute as a subsequent task in the Control Flow above, not in the Data Flow below.)

Fair warning:  the SQL Server 2005 version of SSIS has many, many, many bugs and frustrations which were fixed or improved in later versions of SQL Server.  Even if you just go to SQL Server 2008 you will save yourself many headaches.